# Scalable Background image with min and max constraints

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking for a solution to an odd problem with a difficult client. The site is built in Wordpress using a variation of a fluid 960.gs. So .container_16 is the containing CSS class. Let's say the class looks like this:

```
.container_16 {
background: url(http://image.jpg) no-repeat; 
min-width:960px;
min-height:614px;
max-width:1200px;
max-height:800px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
   }
```

I'd like the full div to scale between a max and min proportional size. I can't figure this out trying a few of the JQuery plugins that I've found like backstretcher. I was using Supersized which worked great expect there is no way that I can figure out to add a max size or have the whole thing center when it reaches a max size which is why I am looking at using a background div.

Any help with this greatly appreciated as I have a client breathing down my neck and I am a designer, not a developer. Thanks!

---

Here is the code I found that appears to be working:

```
$(function(){  $('.container_16 *').css({'background':'transparent','zIndex':2,'position':'relative'});  
$('.container_16').css({'overflow':'hidden','position':'relative'});  
    var containerWidth = $('.container_16').innerWidth();  
    var bgimgurl = $('.container_16').css('backgroundImage').replace(/url\(|\)|"|'/g,"");  
    var img = $('<img src="'+bgimgurl+'" width="100%" />').css({'position':'absolute','left':0,'top':0,'zIndex':1});  
    $('.container_16').css({'background':'transparent'}).append(img);});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
 $(window).resize(function() {

   var h = $(window).height();
   var w = $(window).width();
   if((h<615) || (w<961)){
   $('#container_16').width(960);
   $('#container_16').height(614);

     }else if((h>799) || (w>1199)){
   $('#container_16').width(1200);
   $('#container_16').height(800);

     }else{
       proportional_w = h/3*2;
      $('#container_16').width(h);
      $('#container_16').height(proportional_w);

     }

  });
```

Not sure I understand the question correctly though, but this does re-size the div based on browser size. I do use id instead of class though, since I think it's the only div on the page (judging by its size).

Ok, I've played with that supersize plugin. The startwidth and startheight I think can be used as your max height and width.
On css side you can add to the existing styles that they have in the deom:

```
            html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
    body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
            #supersize{     
    max-height: 400px;
    max-width: 916px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
        }
```

Not sure about how vertical centering will work on different size monitors though, but it's centered horizontally and on my laptop looks fine vertically as well.

Comment: That kind of does it, but it's not a smooth scale. I'm really looking for something like Supersized that has a max scale. I thought maybe doing it with a div would be easier since it can then be centered when it does reach that max scale. Does that make sense?

Comment: I found something that is working, but it is getting removing all of the background images and only leaving the one. Maybe a div that is only for the background image?

Comment: I've added some code above that appears to be working, but it is removing all of the other background CSS images that I am using (in the navigation etc). Not sure how this script is working. Maybe I need to add another div purely for the background image and place it behind everything else using z-index? Any ideas?

Comment: But in supersize plugin you just set max-height and max-width values for #supersize div - I've tried it, works fine in FF at least.

Comment: Weird, it's not working for me. You mean #supersized, right? The position:relative makes the image disappear, removing that and nothing changes as far as scaling is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to Supersized; to set the max width and heights open supersized.css that comes with the Supersized Plugin find the line:

```
#supersized img { width:auto; 
                  height:auto; 
                  position:relative; 
                  display:none; 
                  outline:none; 
                  border:none; 
                  margin:15%; }
```

and change it to:

```
#supersized img {
max-width:1800px; /*whatever max width you want*/
max-height:1000px; /*whatever max height you want*/
position:relative;
display:none;
outline:none;
border:none;
}
```

hope that helps.